# Ошибка в подключении к базе данных Flask

Tags: база-данных, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Изучаю подключение к базам данных во Flask. Скачал код отсюда: https://github.com/drucoder/flask-sweater/tree/SqlAlchemy
Но при запуске происходит ошибка

```
C:\Users\Виктор_2\Desktop\flask-sweater>python start.py
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2138, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 387, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 29, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1033, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1025, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3860, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1919, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1912, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2103, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2142, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1456, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2138, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 387, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.

Comment: Ну так сервер БД запущен-то?